# Как закруглить края изображения?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qpixmap

Я учусь делать приложения на *PyQt5*, и у меня появилась задача закруглить края изображения.

Есть ли какой-то способ сделать это с помощью модуля *PyQt* или посредством самого *Python*? 
Конечно, ответы на такие вопросы стоит искать в гугле, но я уже потратил достаточно много времени на это, заглядывал в учебник *PyQt* и ничего не нашел.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
button.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton {
                            border: none;
                            margin: 0px;
                            padding: 0px;
                        }''')
button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('picture1.png'))
button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 140))

box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(button)
window.setLayout(box)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Это нужно делать через CCS, в PyQt. Т.е меняешь HTML изображения и задаешь там параметры через CSS. (А еще, я плохо объясняю))

Comment: мне кажется, что я вам отвечал на подобный вопрос?  Всегда показывайте пример, в котором вы пытаетесь что-то сделать, а также пишите что вы пробовали. Покажите пример с вашим изображением, края, которого вы хотите закруглить.

Comment: @S.Nick, да, вы отвечали на подобный вопрос и в комментарии добавили, что было бы проще вывести закругленное изображение на кнопке сразу. Поэтому я стал искать, как это сделать:) Честно говоря, я могу прикрепить только код создания кнопки, что мне показалось бесполезным

Comment: @h4cktivist, не подскажете, что можно конкретно почитать на счет этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда я писал в комментарии, то имел ввиду, 
что изображение уже изначально круглое (см. `head3.png`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вы пошли дальше и неправильно сформулировали вопрос,
я бы спросил так: '**Есть картинка формата `.jpg` или `.png`, как средствами `PyQt5` 
обрезать ее так, чтобы она стала круглой.**'
Пример изображения `head2.jpg`, а получить хочу `head3.png` смотрите выше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я продемонстрирую вам это, взяв за основу мой ответ из предыдущего вашего вопроса.

> QIcon::QIcon(const QPixmap &pixmap)
>
> Создает значок из растрового изображения.

```
self.icon = QIcon(self.target)
```

> bool QPixmap::save(const QString &fileName, const char *format = nullptr, int quality = -1) const
>
> Сохраняет растровое изображение в файл с заданным именем файла, 
>   используя указанный формат файла изображения и коэффициент качества. 
>   Возвращает true в случае успеха; в противном случае возвращает false.

**Остальное прокомментировано по тексту кода.
Нажмите на любую кнопку.**

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, antialiasing=True, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Antialiasing = antialiasing
        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 70 

        self.target = QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(Qt.transparent)    

        p = QPixmap("head2.jpg").scaled(  
            140, 140, Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QPainter(self.target)
        if self.Antialiasing:
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(
            0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

        # QIcon::QIcon(const QPixmap &pixmap)
        # Создает значок из растрового изображения.
        self.icon = QIcon(self.target)                                     # +++

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit() 


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # когда я писал в комментарии, то имел ввиду, 
        # что изображение уже изначально круглое (см. `head3.png`)
        self.buttonCircularImage = QPushButton(clicked=self.onClicked)          # +++
        self.buttonCircularImage.setFixedSize(145, 145)
        self.buttonCircularImage.setIcon(QIcon("head3.png"))
        self.buttonCircularImage.setIconSize(QSize(140, 140))

        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.button = QPushButton(clicked=lambda: print('button'))                                             # +++
        self.button.setFixedSize(145, 145)
        self.button_2 = QPushButton(clicked=lambda: print('button_2'))                                           # +++
        self.button_2.setFixedSize(145, 145)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonCircularImage)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: green;")     

    def onClicked(self):
        name = 'image_save'                    # так будет называться новое изобразение         
        if name:
            pixmap = self.label.icon.pixmap(140, 140, QIcon.Normal, QIcon.On)
            _icon = "{}.png".format(name)      # image_save.png - так будет называться новое изобразение 
            pixmap.save(_icon, quality = -1)   # Сохраняет растровое изображение в файл с заданным именем файла 

            # Это как бы по ходу дела
            self.button.setIcon(self.label.icon)
            self.button.setIconSize(QSize(140, 140))
            self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

            # Это загружает из сохраненного файла 'image_save.png'
            self.button_2.setIcon(QIcon(_icon))        # _icon = 'image_save.png'
            self.button_2.setIconSize(QSize(140, 140))
            self.layout.addWidget(self.button_2)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]