# Как для QLabel модуля PyQt5 создать второе визуальное состояние, которое данный виджет будет принимать при нажатии мыши?(Python3)

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qlabel, qpixmap

С помощью модуля *PyQt5* я создал виджет **`QLabel`** и добавил в него изображение.

С помощью метода **`mouseReleaseEvent`** заставил этот виджет реагировать на нажатие мыши.

Теперь я хотел изменить внешний вид `QLabel` при нажатии - затемнить изображение. Из-за некоторых обстоятельств я не могу создать просто кнопку и в таблице стиля задать внешние характеристики кнопки при щелчке, как делал раньше.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как задать второе состояние виджета `QLabel`?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__()
        self.picture = picture
        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent) 

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.label = Label('picture1.png', self)
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label) 

    def onClicked(self):
        print('Вы сделали клик')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: своими "обстоятельствами" вы отсекли самый очевидный и простой способ.. может стоит пересмотреть обстоятельства?

Comment: @finally, второе состояние я делаю исключительно из эстетических соображений. И обстоятельства появились из-за них тоже - мне нужно было закруглить края изображения. Т.к. я не знаю размер картинки, которую должен получить класс, не могу закруглить края сразу и вывести на кнопке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`mouseReleaseEvent` - это отпустить**

**`mousePressEvent` - это нажать.**

Следующий пример на этом и построим. Будем излучать сигнал и там и там.
В зависимости от переданных сигналом данных, подставим то или другое изображение.

Картинки, которые я использую в этом примере, я публиковал вот в этом вопросе [Как закруглить края изображения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081615/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)                              # +  str

    def __init__(self, picture, parent=None):
        super(Label, self).__init__()
        self.picture = picture
        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent) 

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):                              # +++
        self.clicked.emit('Press')

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):                            
        self.clicked.emit('Release')                               # + 'Release'


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.label = Label('head2.jpg', self)
        self.label.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label) 

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def onClicked(self, text):                                       # + text
        if text == 'Press':
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('head3.png'))
        else:
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('head2.jpg').scaled(
                140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            )
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS. Зачем вам знать размер картинки ? Почитайте что такое `scaled`.

```
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('head2.jpg').scaled(
            140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        )
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Завтра утром буду разбирать код:)

Comment: с утра почитаете https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled-1 и расскажите, что такое `scaled`  и зачем оно вам нужно.

Comment: scaled возращает экземпляр QSize, который хранит новые размеры объекта. QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding и QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation - необязательные параметры. Первый параметр пытается сохранить прежнии пропорции объекта, а второй параметр делает какие-то сложные преобразования с изображениями. Почему-то QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation не описан в справочнике. В данном случае scaled я использовал, чтобы изменить размер картинки, которую загрузил QPixmap

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, что почитать, чтобы затемнить картинку при нажатии? Есть какой-то специальный метод, который контролирует цветовую гамму изображения, или нужно создавать какую-нибуть маску, настраивать ее цвет и прозрачность?

Comment: Вы, наверное, в моем вопросе прочитали не "затемнить", а "изменить", поэтому спрашиваю дополнительного совета :)

Comment: @MAXIM045  я прочитал правильно. Обычно заранее готовят изображения в нужных цветовых гаммах,
а в приложении подставляют то или иное. 
То что вы задумали это трудоемкая задача, помните об этом.
А читать нужно  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#details  и  https://arboook.com/kompyuternoe-zrenie/operatsii-s-tsvetom-v-opencv3-i-python/   и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо. Не подскажете, что будет менее ресурсозатратно - изменять размер картинки, закруглять ее края и накладывать на кнопку или использовать QLabel?

Comment: @MAXIM045  готовьте изображения нужных вам размеров и форм, а также цветовой палитры - заранее. В приложении вы должны только подставлять то либо иное.

Comment: Дело в том, что я делаю mp3-плеер для школьного проекта:) он извлекает обложки музыкальных композиций самостоятельно и хранит в определенной папке. Настраивать картинки заранее возможности не имею